# PHP - hash objects in a way distint object with same fields values have same hash

Tags: php, performance, hash

I am looking for a way to generate some kind of hash for PHP object (generic solution, working with all classed, built-in and custom, if possible).

SplObjectStorage::getHash is not what I'm looking for, as it will generate different hash for every instance of given class. To picture the problem, let's consider simple class:

```
class A() {
public $field; //public only for simplicity
}
```

and 2 instances of that class:

```
$a = new A(); $a->field = 'b';
$b = new A(); $b->field = 'b';
```

Every built-in function I've tried will return different hashes for these objects, while I'd like to have some `function f($x)` with property `f($a) == f($b) => $a == $b`.

I am aware I could write a function traversing all object's properties recursively until I find a property that can be casted to string, concatenate this strings in fancy way and hash, but the performance of such solution would be awful.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you could serialize the objects then md5 the serialized object. Since the serialization creates the same string if all properties are the same, you should get the same hash every time. Unless your object has some kind of timestamp property. Example:

```
class A {
    public $field;
}
$a = new A;
$b = new A;
$a->field = 'test';
$b->field = 'test';
echo md5(serialize($a)) . "\n";
echo md5(serialize($b)) . "\n";
```

output:

```
0a0a68371e44a55cfdeabb04e61b70f7
0a0a68371e44a55cfdeabb04e61b70f7
```

Yours are coming out differently because the object in php memory is stored with a numbered id of each instantiation:

```
object(A)#1 (1) {...
object(A)#2 (1) {...
```

Comment: Of course, *internally* this does exactly what the OP suggested: "traversing all object's properties recursively ... casted to string, concatenate ... in fancy way". But this way will be much more efficient and less error-prone than trying to implement all that in user-space. :)

Comment: Ahh good point. I hadn't considered that. I was thinking he meant having to write a function to traverse it.

Comment: To be clear, I think serialization is probably the correct solution, and voted your answer up. Ultimately, anything which needs to compare the values of two deep structures will have to recursively examine those structures - whether that's `serialize`, `var_dump`, or a manual stack-and-loop. Even with raw memory access, you would need to recursively follow pointers to other areas of memory. Similarly, anything which needs to hash a data structure must first flatten it into a standard byte representation, so there is no avoiding the string cast either.

Comment: I think var_dump just grabs the string from memory that gets converted to an object when accessed. And I agree, if it were me I'd definitely use serialize.

Comment: Nevermind you were right, it does traverse the object.

Comment: Why would it point to a string? That would be *incredibly* inefficient. The memory structure for even simple variables in PHP is a complex set of pointers and metadata called a `zval`. Browsing the source, the definition of a structure called `zend_object` in PHP 5.6 is here: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend.h#312

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was looking for something exactly like that when I realized I was wrong lol. I realized I had not thought about it before in enough detail until you raised the question. If you know any more links or literature on the internals of php, please share.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Robert Cathey. I do am considering serialization in the last resort. What concerns me, beyond the performance of this solution, is that some objects cannot be serialized according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php. I'm not sure though which ones exactly aren't serializable - I might be able to accept that and/or define some kind of fallback mode for them.

Comment: I've never had an object that couldn't serialize. That link says it handles all variable types except the resource type, which doesn't include objects. It's a special type of variable. I honestly don't think you'll have any trouble out of this.

Comment: Hm, that is a good point actually - certain kinds of internal object aren't serializable because they encapsulate some non-PHP data structure. This includes resource-y things like PDO connections, but also more abstract data like SimpleXMLElement (which points to an internal LibXML parse tree).

Comment: While not perfect, it seems to be the best I can get at the moment. For the record - I was considering json_encode for a while, as a more efficient option but 1) json_encode vs serialize battle result varies with PHP version 2) it only uses public fields, which is not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be talking about a Value Object. It is a pattern where each such object isn't compared according to the object identity, but about the contents - fully, or partially, of the properties that make up the object.

I'm using a number of them in a project:

```
public function equals(EmailAddress $address)
{
    return strtolower($this->address) === strtolower((string) $address);
}
```

A more complex object could simply add more items into the comparison function.

```
return ($this->one === $address->getOne() && 
    $this->two === $address->getTwo());
```

As such conditionals (all joined with '&&') will short-cut to false as soon as any item does not match.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question as currently framed, which specifically talks about hashing, not direct comparison, and about "generic solution, working with all classes, built-in and custom", not just a subset of classes implementing a particular interface.

Answer (score 0):

The question, in effect, asks for two things that may be at odds with one another.

1. A method of hashing any object in a consistent (and performant) manner.
2. Efficient comparison of objects using this hashing method.

First, the hash. Others have suggested `serialize()` for performance reasons but it does introduce one limitation: PHP objects can have fields added externally as well as those declared in the class. So it's possible (although unlikely and certainly indicative of questionable coding practice) that your objects could have the same fields, but declared in different order. This would produce different serializations, which by the wording of your question you would not want.

To guard against this, you would need to cast the object to an array and sort its members. In case any fields are themselves objects or arrays that may have the same issue, you should work recursively.

```
function sortObject($obj) {
  $arr = (array) $obj;
  ksort($arr);
  foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if(is_array($v) || is_object($v)) {
      $arr[$k] = sortObject($v);
    }
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

This provides a consistent representation of the object that can be serialized and hashed. Alternatively you can actually build the hash within the function itself:

```
function hashObject($obj) {
  $arr = (array) $obj;
  ksort($arr);
  $hash = '';
  foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if(is_array($v)) {
      $hash .= '['.hashObject($v).']';
    elseif(is_object($v)) {
      $hash .= '{'.hashObject($v).'}';
    } else {
      $hash .= var_export($v);
    }
  }
  return $hash;
}
//The brackets are added to preserve structure.
```

`json_encode()` could be used in place of `var_export()` but I chose the latter to guarantee faithful representation of PHP values (collisions might be possible in JSON, I dunno) and I suspect it might perform better.

Then again, what if an object contains circular references, e.g. it has an object or array field containing a value that is a reference back to it? `serialize()` can handle that; the functions above cannot.

Now: comparing. The best approach to this is governed by *what the answer is most likely to be*. That is to say:

If you expect most of the pairs of objects you are comparing to differ, then it will be more efficient to compare them piece-by-piece, so you can establish difference as soon as possible.

```
function matchObj($a,$b) {
  if(gettype($a) !== gettype($b)) {
    return false;
  }
  $arrA = (array) $a;
  $arrB = (array) $b;
  if(count($arrA) <> count($arrB)) {
    return false;
  }
  ksort($arrA);
  ksort($arrB);
  foreach($arrA as $k => $v) {
    if($k !== key($arrB) || gettype($v) !== gettype($arrB[$k]) {
      return false;
    }
    if(is_array($v) || is_object($v)) {
      matchObj($v,$arrB[$k]) || return false;
    } elseif($v !== $arrB[$k]) {
      return false;
    }
    next($arrB);
  }
  return true;
}
```

If you expect most of the pairs to match, then you may as well hash each object in full and compare those (which is likely to work out more efficient if using `serialize()` than your own recursive function like the above) because you won't have much of a shortcut to the answer in each instance anyway.