# Sync data without knowing last modifed timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, integration

This probably is a common question but for some reason I have not found the correct words to search for it. The problem is:

How can I sync data from one system to another (one way) without knowing when and if the data has changed?

Lets say there is a server called PersonProvider and my sever called MyServer. MyServer will regularly poll using PersonProvder API and get a response containing an array of persons such as:

```
[
   { id: 1, name: "Adam A", city: "A city", salary: 1010, ... },
   { id: 2, name: "Bart B", city: "B city", salary: 1222, ... },
   ...
]
```

This information will be stored in MyServers MySQL database.

Most commonly the information will not change apart from salary. What could happen is that new persons could be added. Of course a person could move or even change his/her name and then MyServer should get the information as soon as possible. PersonProvider doesn't have a way to tell if any of the persons' information has been changed and doesn't contain any last modified timestamp.

One way I can think of is to make a checksum of the data from PersonProvider and save it. I wounder if that would be enough or if a checksum actually could be same even if the data change.

So how can I know if PersonProviders data is newer than MyServers data?

Comment: Does the data has any unique ID? If not you should change your table and add a primary key. Without primary key there isn't any way to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Yes, the unique ID is there, I just forgot to mention. Duplicate data can be solved. My question is more how I can reduce overwrite existing if they mostly are the same. As more I think of it the more silly my question sounds.

Comment: Without timestamps its not possible. You need a last_modified timestamp. If not you will have to manually compare new rows with old rows to find out whether they were updated.

Comment: Have you tried to turn each client into an object in PHP and hash the object line by line and store it someway?

Maybe you can check this to see if fits

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659187/php-hash-objects-in-a-way-distint-object-with-same-fields-values-have-same-has